# Preprocessor giving compilation while declaring unsigned int x and initializing with a binary constant

Tags: c, compilation, int, preprocessor, unsigned

I am getting error in Pro* C pre-compilation when I have declared the variables as

```
unsigned int x = 0b00001;
unsigned int y = 0b00010;
unsigned int z = 0b00100;
```

When the pre-compilation happens in pro*c , error is

```
    ....................1
    PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "B00001" when expecting one of the following
    :

       ; , = ( [ * ? | & < > + - / % . ^ *= /= %= += -= <<= >>= &&=
       ||= ^= | & == != <= >= << >> ++ -- ->
    The symbol ";" was substituted for "B00001" to continue.

    GCC version is 
    gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC)`enter code here`
```

When I try to run this code as a normal C code in a different file, it works just fine.  The issue only occurs while running a pro*c code.

So, I want to understand what the exact problem is when a proc code is compiled and why no problem when C code compiles.

Comment: `0b00001` is not standard C, try `1`.

Comment: Where are the preprocessor directives? I mean, which part is handled by the preprocessor?

Comment: @chux gcc seems to be okay with it. Apparently an extension.

Comment: @chux
do you mean to say unsigned int x = 1; ?

Comment: Yes. Try `x=1; y = 2; z = 4;`

Comment: that works fine. But I want to do something like show them in binary.

Comment: can you please check this. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm

Comment: @RohanChitnis Then use non-standard C or `enum bit { B00000, B00001, B00010, B00011, B00100 };` or the like.  There are no binary integer constants in standard C.